# ReactJS OnClick Function to render Dates on selected Dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an on-click event function to render data on specific days.

The onClick function doesn't work properly and renders the data regardless of what day it is, I've tried a lot of different methods like: filter, sort, map and conditional rendering.

I'm a bit of a loss at this point.

What solution or method should I look up in order to get to my end goal?

Here's a part of my repo of where my code is being called: [Github](https://github.com/PrinceJelly/issues/blob/main/code-block)

Here's my codesandbox to spare you from details: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/calendar-h4lp1?file=/src/calendar.js)

Also here's a demo of what I'm trying to accomplish by another guy's sandbox. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rudcj?file=/src/components/Games.js)

Thank you so much!

Comment: you used two event, `onChange` and `onClickDay`, i think, that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
  const OnClickDay = (event) => {
    console.log("event", event);//this is selected date 
    // selectedValue is wrong, it is prev selected(click) date
    
  };
```

```
  onClickDay={(e) => {
          OnClickDay(e);
  }}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, although, i'm trying to render my data based on the corresponding dates. I'm not sure how I would approach this.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by another person! Thanks so much for everyone's input.

For any lost souls that stumbles upon this post... here's what's been forked from a redditor! [Answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/calendar-forked-wn982?file=/src/calendar.js)

> There are two approaches:
>
> onclick, filter the events, set the event state, and map them to html
>
> onclick, set the date state, filter and map to html at the same time
>
> Assuming the first solution, your "event" variable is a const, its not
> using useState. You'll notice the other guy's has useState for their
> "game" variable.
>
> When you call onClick, its just updating a variable to true. You need
> to filter the events and update an events state variable.

[Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/kjajv9/need_a_bit_of_help_with_my_code/)